# asp.net to tomcat

Tags: asp.net, tomcat, deployment, mono, intranet

Anyone has any example/tutorial links to deploy asp.net to tomcat (intranet) using mono? The guide they gave isn't clear on how it should be done.

Or are there any other ways to deploy asp.net to tomcat other than using mono?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here is a small example http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyone has any example/tutorial links to deploy asp.net to tomcat
>   (intranet) using mono?

Since Tomcat is mainly intended for running Java based technology you should probably look into things like [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130) although I haven't seen anyone using Tomcat to deploy ASP.NET applications so far.

> Or are there any other ways to deploy asp.net to tomcat other than
>   using mono?

If your environment is unix based then your only way how to do that is using mono. I would however recommend you to use either apache with [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) or nginx with [FastCGI](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx) since these are the most used combinations of running ASP.NET based web applications with mono.